# Floating panel in GWT

Tags: css, gwt

I'm developing application with GWT 2 and would like to add float panel that stick to the bottom of the screen (not page, like chat panel in facebook). What is the best way to make that kind of panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should apply the style below to a Panel (any basic Panel should do: `FlowPanel`, `HTMLPanel`, etc) and add it to the body (it doesn't *have* to be `<body>` but we know that it's always there and won't be removed ;)) via `RootPanel.get().add(fixedPanel);`

```
position: absolute; /* Or fixed - depends on what you want */
right: 0; /* The part that puts the Panel in bottom right of the page/client area */
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by adding the CSS attribute `position: fixed` to the div in question.

Read more here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html

Comment: But how do I put it on the bottom-right corner of the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by CSS. All you need is any GWT Panel and then style it using CSS. Check out http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/