# How to Keep the Button(widget) in Screen in Scrolling view?

Tags: java, css, jakarta-ee, gwt, gwt-rpc

Assume page size is longer than screen size(length), i had created one button, if i scroll the page upside button keep in screen up side and if i scroll down side button should be keep in bottom of the screen. I am new to GWT, how can i get, help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to GWT as well but from what it sounds like to me is more a CSS/HTML attribute issue than a direct GWT/JAVA/JS issue since ideally the final display is controlled via HTML/CSS elements. (The look and feel and position of your objects with GWT)

I found a similar question with a few answers that should help.

I would used a certain Panel for this button object and give it a unique CSS tag so it stays in the bottom on the screen but not with the (assuming) content div(s) tags.

Hope this helps or points you in the right direction. I like your idea though.

[Similar StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633762/floating-panel-in-gwt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both GWT and CSS. I will provide some pointers on how you could do it
I would create a css class, but that would keep it to the top of the page

```
.buttonStyle {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
```

Or use the ScrollHandler, do the math by the properties of the Event and

```
Window.addWindowScrollHandler(new Window.ScrollHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onWindowScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
        // Check if the event is up or down change the style appropriately
        // If it is down you must check the window size and change the top attribute
        // of the Style as top = WindowSize - ButtonSize
        int windowHeight = Window.getClientHeight();
        int buttonHeight = btnWidget.getOffsetWidth();
        int newTop = windowHeight -buttonHeight;
        btnWidget.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("top", newTop +"px" );
    }
});
```